# asfreq in pandas returns an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm tring to use infer_freq and asfreq and the return data frame is empty

Original data set:

```
    month   interest
0   2004-01 13
1   2004-02 15
2   2004-03 17
3   2004-04 19
4   2004-05 22
```

Trying to convert the data with different frequency

```
ice_cream_interest = pd.read_csv('ice_cream_interest.csv')
ice_cream_interest.set_index('month', inplace=True)
ice_cream_interest = ice_cream_interest.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(ice_cream_interest.index))
```

```
    interest
month   
2004-01-01  NaN
2004-02-01  NaN
2004-03-01  NaN
2004-04-01  NaN
2004-05-01  NaN
... ...
2020-04-01  NaN
2020-05-01  NaN
2020-06-01  NaN
2020-07-01  NaN
2020-08-01  NaN
```

Comment: I don't think your question adequately describes what you are trying to do. As far as just "using" `infer_freq` and `asfreq` ... so far so good, they are being used (I don't mean to be smart here - just literally that is the case).

Comment: So why the data frame return empty ?

Comment: that result is not an empty dataframe.

Comment: 'interest'  column is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
     month  interest
0  2004-01        13
1  2004-02        15
2  2004-03        17
3  2004-04        19
4  2004-05        22
```

Doing:

```
# Convert to datetime
df.month = pd.to_datetime(df.month)

# Set Index
df = df.set_index('month')

# Convert to freq
df = df.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(df.index))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            interest
month
2004-01-01        13
2004-02-01        15
2004-03-01        17
2004-04-01        19
2004-05-01        22

>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-01', '2004-02-01', '2004-03-01', '2004-04-01',
               '2004-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='month', freq='MS')
```

We can see it successfully converted to a frequency index.

Answer (score 1):

I want to quote from the documentation of [`asfreq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html).

> The values corresponding to any timesteps in the new index which were not present in the original index will be null (NaN).

The problem is, that in your example the dates in the index are still strins and the given datetime object by the `asfreq()`-method do not exist yet. You can solve this, transforming your "months" to datetime-objects first.

Please see the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['2004-01', '2004-02', '2004-03', '2004-04', '2004-05'],
    'interest': [13, 15,17, 19, 22]
})
```

If we transform the months into a datetime object first, we get

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
df = df.set_index('month')
print(df.index.values) # this is a list of datetime objects
>>> ['2004-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2004-02-01T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2004-03-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2004-04-01T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2004-05-01T00:00:00.000000000']
df = df.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(df.index))
df
>>>
            interest
month               
2004-01-01        13
2004-02-01        15
2004-03-01        17
2004-04-01        19
2004-05-01        22
```

Doing the same without this transformation

```
# df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
df = df.set_index('month')
print(df.index.values)  # this is still a list strings
>>> ['2004-01' '2004-02' '2004-03' '2004-04' '2004-05']

df = df.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(df.index))
df
>>>
            interest
month               
2004-01-01       NaN
2004-02-01       NaN
2004-03-01       NaN
2004-04-01       NaN
2004-05-01       NaN
```